# Check if an item already exists in a txt file

Tags: vb.net

The following code will save an item to file over and over again, but how do I save an item only once?

```
Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("E:\test.txt", True)
w.WriteLine(ListBox1.SelectedItem, True)
w.Close()
```

If, for example, `number1` is already saved in the txt file then how do I not save it again, using something like the following?

```
dim exist As IO.FileAccess ("e:\s.txt")

if exist.that.item.is.exist= true then
    w.WriteLine(ListBox1.SelectedItem, True)
else
    msg "that item is already in your txt file "
end if
```

For example `listbox1` items are:

> "number1"
>   "number2"
>   "number3"
>   "number 4"

I am using VS 2010.

Comment: What is the data contract for your text file? What rules can you depend on format wise? Will/should there always be 1 unique value per text line?

Comment: in listbox1 items are like "number1" , "number2" ,"number3"

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim hash As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines("E:\test.txt"))

If Not hash.Contains(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) Then
    Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("E:\test.txt", True)
    w.WriteLine(ListBox1.SelectedItem, True)
    w.Close()
Else
    'Item is already in text file
End If
```

Comment: its gives error ::     the method or operation is not implemented      btw i use vs 2010

Comment: its gives error on if Not hash.Contains that "Contains" is not a memeber of windowsApllication3.HasSet(Of String)

Comment: Error 1 'Contains' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication4.HashSet(Of String)'. c:\users\7\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Form1.vb 9 16 WindowsApplication4

Comment: It´s the generic `HashSet` class, from `System.Collections.Generic`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is @Diego code with some minor changes. (I don't have edit privileges yet)

```
    Dim hash As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("E:\test.txt"))

    If Not hash.Contains(ListBox1.SelectedValue) Then
        Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("E:\test.txt", True)
        w.WriteLine(ListBox1.SelectedValue, True)
        w.Close()
    Else
        'Item is already in text file
    End If
```

1. Add System.IO. to File.ReadAllLines
2. Change SelectedItem to SelectedValue

Comment: If a HashSet doesn't work, you can try using a List(Of String) instead.