# Search text file to see if string is present

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to programing so I apologize in advanced.

So I am trying to create a Win App to make copying files using Robocopy easier and eventually other tasks. Basically what I have so far is a Button that calls the Sub Robcopy_EXE. There is a tab on the form with 100 check boxes, one for each terminal, that will be designated by the user and a check box to determine if you want a detailed report or not from Robocopy. I also have a text box for the user to input the first 3 octets of the site IP Address. The check boxes and Input field are used to create string "Terminal_input" which is what runs Robocopy in CMD. Robocopy logs its progress to a text file that I have labeled "Status.txt". That is as far as I have gotten.

At this moment I need to know when the the current running update is done to progress to the the next terminal. I am trying to continuously read the "Status.txt" file and look for the word "ENDED" to progress to the next terminal. If the word "ENDED" is not present I want to update LABEL3 to "Updating Terminal"

Ultimately I would like to have a way of making the checkbox# a variable that increments as it progresses through each checkbox#, but I will mess with that after I figure out how to check for 1 terminal to be completed.

Like I said I'm new to programing and I am having a lot of fun figuring this out, but I am very stumped on this procedure and I am going about it the worst way possible :D

Thanks in advanced.

```
   Private Sub RoboCopy_EXE()
        Dim Robocopystart = "Robocopy C:\wtg\update \\"
        Dim Robocopymid = IP_Input.Text
        Dim Robocopyend = ".42\c$\wtg /E /copy:datsou /r:3 /w:20 /log+:status.txt /tee /ns /nc /nfl /"
        Dim Terminal_Input = Robocopystart + Robocopymid + Robocopyend
        If CheckBox10.Checked Then
            If RoboCopy_Detailed_Progress.Checked = True Then
                Shell("CMD.exe", vbNormalFocus)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
                SendKeys.SendWait(Terminal_Input)
                Label3.Text = items
            Else : RoboCopy_Detailed_Progress.Checked = False
                Shell("CMD.exe", vbNormalFocus)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                SendKeys.Send("Test2")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to add the homework tag.  Whether this is homework or not, it will let people know the level of effort they need to put into an explanation.

Comment: "There is a tab on the form with 100 check boxes" OMG and you will code against it? and the user will have to check them one by one??

Comment: Here is a link to a question I answered with a similar need to check a text file for specific pieces of text. Hopefully this will help you get one step closer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9535904/1231016

Answer (score 0):

There could be probably better ways (and even way betters!) to do this. But for the sake of easy things, you should read about a timer control, and execute it once a second, and check the status of the file. and read the last line and compare it with the one you are looking for.

Comment: I am actually already playing around with timers I just didn't include it with the above code. I figure the concept was cleaner that way. I honestly just need help with the coding for looking into the file for "ENDED" as every attempt I have made doesn't work. As far as there being 100 check boxes, unfortunately this is a must as the Check box # correlates to the last octet of the computer IP Address and the last octet of the computers IP address can be between 10-200 for me. This is much easier for me then typing in the terminals numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How big are these log files? You could do something along the lines of

```
While true
    Dim sr as new StreamReader(fileName)
    Dim contents as String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close
    ForEach(string line in contents)
        if (line = "ENDED") then
            exit While
        Endif
    Next
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
Loop
```

(forgive any syntax errors, written off the top of my head and I'm mainly C# these days)

Although you should probably beef that up with some error handling and a way out of the loop so it doesn't loop forever (if it goes 100 times exit with error?).

Additionally, you should put all that on a BackGroundWorker so it doesn't lock the UI (you will find updating labels and such problematic otherwise).

Finally, instead of 100 checkboxes (yuck!), perhaps a dynamically generated listbox with checked items, or a DataGridView with similar? You could just iterate through the checked items that way.

Comment: This is the line I'm looking for. It is the last line of the log file.

Ended : Thu Apr 12 13:15:30 2012

Sorry for by lack of knowledge how would I go about generating the check boxes dynamically and then output them to the Winapp? Also its actually check box 10-199. The reason for the large number of check boxes is they each represent the last octet of a computer IP address.This is the line I'm looking for. It is the last line of the log file.
Ended : Thu Apr 12 13:15:30 2012